# How could found new item was added to scene?

Tags: c++, qt

does exist an event or some thing like that when a new item is added to scene, informed me?
Thank you in advance

Comment: You can do something every time when you use `addItem` or create your own signal and emit this signal, isn't it?

Comment: I posted this as answer but also in my answer I added similar signal which QGraphicsScene has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such signal or event. Moreover, do we really need this signal? Developer knows when he add item to the scene using the `addItem()` method. So you can create some function and call it when you use `addItem()`. Also if your task is more complex, you can create your own signal and `emit` it when you use `addItem()`. In this case another parts of your program will know that something was added to the scene.

But there is similar signal:

```
void QGraphicsScene::changed(const QList<QRectF> & region) [signal]
```

But this signal emits not only when item was added, so be careful.

From doc:

> This signal is emitted by QGraphicsScene when control reaches the
>   event loop, if the scene content changes. The region parameter
>   contains a list of scene rectangles that indicate the area that has
>   been changed.